# How to use settings.configure() to use specific app settings

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use django within a python shell and am restricted so that I can't change environment variables - ie so can't set 
`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

Instead I tried to use settings.configure() but can't get it to pick up my apps settings.

My project is laid out as (missing out the non important parts)

```
my_project
---config
-------settings
----------common.py
----------local.py
----------prod.py
manage.py
```

Comment: Can you show your code and the error message?

Comment: Are you importing `common.py` in both `local.py` and `prod.py`: `from .common import *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this in "manage.py" file

```
import os
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "What_ever_settings.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Going by the example file structure, for local development, `"What_ever_settings.settings"` would have to point to `"my_project.config.settings.local"`